# Jquery mobile changing formatting, voiding float?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using Jquery mobile for my application. I am using it in one part of my page, but I have discovered that it is ruining the formatting on my listview.

I have the following basic format( fiddle at the bottom )

```
   <ul>
      <li>
         <div id="number1">
            <span></span>
         <div>
         <div id="number2">
             <span><input type="checkbox" /><span>
             <span> something</span>
             <span> something else</span>
         </div>
      </li>
  </ul>
```

I am creating a listview. The inner div with id="number1" is going to be a main label for a list. In the inner div with id="number2" there will be a checkbox and two small buttons inline. I want this to take up minimal space all of the way to the right.

**Problem:** The formatting looks fine as long as I do not check "jQuery Mobile 1.3.0b1", which I am using for other parts of my page. As soon as that is clicked it is as though the float:right on div w. id="number2" is no longer having effect.

http://jsfiddle.net/SteveRobertson/ncQFp/39/

**Check out the fiddle, then check off jQuery Mobile 1.3.0.b1 and see the effect it is having that I do not want.**

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    .ui-controlgroup-horizontal .ui-controlgroup-controls {
    display: block !important;
    }

<li>
    <div id="jobList"  data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
        <div id="labelContainer">
            <span class="labelItem"><a href="#">item 2</a></span>
        </div>
        <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" id="buttonContainer">  
            <span class="checkboxes"><label for="id2"></label><input type="checkbox" id="id2" /></span> 
            <span class="deleteButton"><a href="#"> A</a></span>
            <span class="notesButton"><a href="#"> B</a></span>                                                     
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/7SCKt/)

Not sure how it suppose to look like but hope this will help.